# Django, не могу сохранить картинку

Tags: python, django, изображения, django-orm

Django, не могу сохранить картинку.
нужно  изменить  размер (это получаеться) а, при сохранении выдаёт ошибку

```
spisok1=Pictures.objects.all()
for x in spisok1:
    print(x.id)
    print(x.image)
    print(x.images_resize)
    newimage = Image.open(x.image)
    if newimage.mode not in ("L", "RGB"):
        newimage = newimage.convert("RGB")

    name = x.image.path.split('/')[-1]
    name ='tumb-'+name
    newimage.thumbnail((200, 200), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    newimage.save(name, 'JPEG', quality=75)
    x.images_resize.save(name, newimage.save, save=True)
```

И выдаёт Ошибку :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/xmaster/PycharmProjects/dashaprod/media/masters/photos_resize/obr2.py", line 31, in <module>
    x.images_resize.save(name, newimage.save, save=True)
  File "/home/xmaster/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/files.py", line 94, in save
    self.name = self.storage.save(name, content, max_length=self.field.max_length)
  File "/home/xmaster/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 54, in save
    return self._save(name, content)
  File "/home/xmaster/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 351, in _save
    for chunk in content.chunks():
  File "/home/xmaster/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/files/base.py", line 81, in chunks
    data = self.read(chunk_size)
  File "/home/xmaster/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/files/utils.py", line 16, in <lambda>
    read = property(lambda self: self.file.read)
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'read'
```

куда рыть уже запутался , может кто подскажет  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from io import BytesIO
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile

...

buffer = BytesIO()
newimg.save(fp=buffer, format='JPEG')
x.images_resize.save(name, ContentFile(buffer.getvalue()))
```

Comment: Добавил BytesIO(). Теперь фаил сохраняет в какой-то формат что картинка не читается , чего делать ?

Comment: Сам затупил , спасибо помогло . а что   а что за буфер такой ?

Comment: Позволяет работать с последовательностью байтов как с файловым объектом.Есть такой же для строк. Почитать можно о них в [описании модуля io](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html).